# Why can't I get this setup with a relative layout?

Tags: android, layout

I'm writing an android app where I want to have a table up top, a list at the bottom, and some buttons on the same screen. It's a little busy, but that's my setup. The problem is, I don't know how to get this layout right so that everything stays without laying on top of each other. I've tried each one in android studio.

Here's what I want it to look like:

(Everyone be impressed by my paint skills): 
[image]

To me, the relative layout makes the most sense. However, whenever I add the gridview, I can't get it to have the bottom align with the center of the screen. For example, it just takes over in the designer:

[image]

My question is: Is there a way to make this happen? The top item doesn't need to be clickable, but I do need to dynamically create rows & columns and make it look like a table. Therefore, it can be another control.

Comment: Please post your XML layout file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *If i understand your question correctly you are trying to do as displayed in image snapshot below right ?*

[image]

---

### *Here is the xml for that structure*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:numColumns="3" >
        </GridView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#D7DF01"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#DF01A5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

***Hope it helps !***